# Need Java to loop only one time and create a single column/row

Tags: java, for-loop

This is for an assignment, and is specifically requested. I know it seems somewhat pointless to create a nested for loop that only executes once, so wanted to clarify that.

The assignment question is a bit confusing to me, but states:

"Write a Java program that uses two nested FOR loops. The values used in the outer loop will be a user input value. The inner loop will use the input value divided by 2. Print a simple statement showing the values using the range of 1 to the user input number in the outer loop. The inner loop will print 1 to the divided result." However, the rubric states, "Student properly uses Java and creates a nested FOR loop and prints proper row and column number."

I initially thought I only needed to divide the input value by two and print that value, but now I feel like I'm supposed to print the input value in a simple row and column format? (If anyone else has clarity on this, please don't hesitate to drop a comment)

Basing my code on this, I'm having a really difficult time getting it to execute only once, and also having an issue printing a proper row and column. I'm attaching my attempt at the code below (this is an into-level course, fyi). Any feedback/help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class rowCol {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        System.out.println(" \t1");

        for (n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
            for (n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
                System.out.println("1 \t" + n);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Assume that the number 10 is input. The outer loop should run from 1 to 10; the inner loop goes from 1 to 5 (10 / 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he meant that the outer for loop should run till n ( value entered by user ) and inner for loop will run till n/2 ( divided value )

```
class rowCol {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

//        System.out.println(" \t1");
        
        int val = n/2; 
        
        for (int i  = 1;i<=n; i++) {
            // printing from range 1 to n in the outer loop 
            System.out.print(i);
            for (int j = 1; j<=val; j++) {
                // printing from 1 to divided value in the inner loop 
                System.out.print(" \t" +j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

When you run it , it gives output in this format .
[image]

Comment: This does make sense, thanks! However, when I attempt to run your code, as well as the other answer, I'm not even prompted for an input value. It runs, and keeps running. Is it my compiler? I'm using VS Code for reference.

Comment: for verification purposes, just check if you are able to print "Hello World" on the console ( add in this program before user input ) , are you able to see it in the console ? i did it on eclipse

Comment: I ended up forgetting I needed to add a package. Ugh, sorry. Thank you for your help and insight, it's working great now! I feel like your interpretation of the question is correct, so thank you, again! I cannot even tell you how much time I've spent on this before asking here haha

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are accepting the value from the user in the variable `n` and then later changing it to `0` in the loop. Doing this you are loosing the input you took from the user. You won't be able to calculate the `n/2` if you loose what you accepted from the user in the first place.

You'll have to define different variables/counters for your two loops. Your outer loop will go from `1` to the number you accepted and the inner one will go from `1` to the half of the number you accepted from the user.

Your final code should look something like this (for illustration purposes only):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class rowCol {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
            // Print Row Number
            System.out.print("Row: " + row + "\t");
            for (int col = 1; col <= n/2; col++) {
                // Print Column Number
                System.out.print("Column: " + col + "\t");
            }
            // Print New Line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```